# How to use Magento 2’s built in Vagrant box?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, zend-framework, vagrant

With a clean checkout of Magento 2.0 on branch 2.0, I’ve run `composer install`. Included in the dependencies is a Vagrant configuration file in `vendor/magento/zendframework1`.

While it seems like this would be a great built in resource, it doesn’t seem to be working properly, and it’s not clear if the VM is designed to be an out of the box Vagrant box for Magento 2, or something geared towards the Zend Framework.

If it is in the repository for a purpose, what is that purpose and how should I set it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a virtual machine for ZF1 unit testing and library development.

The package "magento/zendframework1" is based on [ZendFramework1 code source](http://github.com/zendframework/zf1) . The Vagrantfile is included into zf1 for [development using a virtual machine](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/DEVELOPMENT_README.md)

I am not sure, that Vagrant file in zend framework will deal with magento.

I would advice to try [AlexP's Vagrant project for Magento 2 developers (optimized for Mac, Windows and *nix hosts)*](https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers), which is implemented for magento2 developers. I use it on day by day basis.

Comment: Thanks ArkadiyCh, I’m aware of the various Magento Vagrant boxes & thanks for your recommendation, but I’m more interested in why the Vagrant box is included in the codebase - if it’s not in there for a reason, why include it at all? if it is in the codebase for a reason, what’s the reason and how dow I make use of it?

Comment: The package "magento/zendframework1" is based on https://github.com/zendframework/zf1. I think this Vagrantfile is included into zf1 for [development using a virtual machine](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/DEVELOPMENT_README.md)

Comment: Yes - Vagrant is software that creates a VM for development - understood - is the inclusion of the zf1 Vagrant box in Magento 2 for the purpose of developing Magento 2, or only the Zend framework?

Comment: only the Zend framework. It's a virtual machine for ZF1 unit testing and library development.

Comment: Thanks ArkadiyCh. I think that was the answer I was looking for. I find it odd that Magento 2 contains a VM to develop another platform - understanding that Magento 2 requires the Zend framework to run, I think it should include only the files from the framework it needs.

Comment: are you running your vagrant box on linux or windows?

Comment: Tested on hosts such as windows and macOs, the guest machine is ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have been spent around 1 with to build vagrant & ansible for running with magento 2.

I have just publish its result yesterday via [github](https://github.com/giappv/vagrant_magento2).

I stayed at `/vagrant/htdocs` and ran this command:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

It now downloads latest version magento community 2.0.1

I could run `composer install` properly.
After setting up magento 2, please remember do these commands

For downloading static content, it helps you prevent slow slow problem.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

For downloading sample data

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

For installing sample data

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If you meet any issue, please feel free to leave comment.

Comment: Thx gurutheme.com, but I’m more interested in why there’s a Vagrant box included in the repo and how to use it than additional set ups.

Comment: which tool do you use for developing your magento now?